# Find text strings that have changed in HTML files

Tags: html, git, grep

I need to change some terminology used in my web app. I have a bunch of HTML files in my git repository, and I want to find all occurrences of certain strings in the *text* of the HTML. I don't want to match strings in the tags because changing that would require changes in my scripts as well. Maybe I'll change them too later for consistency, but for now I just want to focus on the UI.

Suppose I want to replace "Assessment" with something else. Given:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in assessments">
     <h4>Assessment {{item.title}}</h4>
</li>
```

I just want to know that there's something on the second line that needs to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git has a feature called [`textconv`](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Textconv) that can do transformations on files before presenting them. Usually this is used to display diffs of binary files, but you can use it to convert anything.

1. Install [`html2text`](http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/).
2. Add this to your `~/.gitconfig`:

   ```
   [diff "html"]
       textconv=html2text
   ```
3. Add this to your repository's `.gitattributes` file:

   ```
   *.html diff=html
   ```
4. Run `git grep` with the `--textconv` option:

   ```
   git grep --textconv -i assessment -- *.html
   # * *** Assessment {{item.title}} ***
   ```

Textconv is off by default for `git grep`, but on by default for `git diff`. So you'll probably want to remove that line from `.gitattributes` after you're done, otherwise you'll have to run `git diff --no-textconv` to see the changes to the tags (and make patches).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `git grep` with submodules, make sure to use Git 2.34+ (Q4 2021):

"[`git grep --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1fdfb774aaaa0ee8acb0a1ec9b601e5a2d2999f1/Documentation/git-grep.txt#L63)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt---recurse-submodules))</sup> takes trees and blobs from the submodule repository, but the `textconv` settings when processing a blob from the submodule are not taken from the submodule repository.

See [commit 45bde58](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45bde58ef8f521e7deb730ffe90040b58d11af64) (29 Sep 2021) by [Matheus Tavares (`matheustavares`)](https://github.com/matheustavares).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1fdfb77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fdfb774aaaa0ee8acb0a1ec9b601e5a2d2999f1), 13 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`grep`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45bde58ef8f521e7deb730ffe90040b58d11af64): demonstrate bug with `textconv` attributes and submodules
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matheus Tavares</sup>

> In some circumstances, "[`git grep --textconv --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/45bde58ef8f521e7deb730ffe90040b58d11af64/Documentation/git-grep.txt#L74)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt---textconv))</sup> ignores the `textconv` attributes from the submodules and erroneously applies the attributes defined in the superproject on the submodules files.
> The `textconv` cache is also saved on the superproject, even for submodule objects.
>
> A fix for these problems will probably require at least three changes:
>
> - Some `textconv` and attributes functions (as well as their callees) will have to be adjusted to work with arbitrary repositories.
>   Note that `"fill_textconv()`", for example, already receives a "`struct repository`" but it writes the `textconv` cache using `"write_loose_object()`", which implicitly works on `"the_repository"`.
> - [`grep.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/45bde58ef8f521e7deb730ffe90040b58d11af64/grep.c) functions will have to call `textconv/userdiff` routines passing the "`repo`" field from "`struct grep_source`" instead of the one from "`struct grep_opt`".
>   The latter always points to "`the_repository`" on "[`git grep`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/45bde58ef8f521e7deb730ffe90040b58d11af64/Documentation/git-grep.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep))</sup> executions (see its initialization in [`builtin/grep.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/45bde58ef8f521e7deb730ffe90040b58d11af64/builtin/grep.c)), but the former points to the correct repository that each source (an object, file, or buffer) comes from.
> - "`userdiff_find_by_path()`" might need to use a different attributes stack for each repository it works on or reset its internal static stack when the repository is changed throughout the calls.
>
> For now, let's add some tests to demonstrate these problems, and also update a `NEEDSWORK` comment in [`grep.h`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/45bde58ef8f521e7deb730ffe90040b58d11af64/grep.h) that mentions this bug to reference the added tests.

So this issue is not fixed yet, but is at least documented for future work.